# What can cause CICS transaction to write out of CICS allocated memory?

Tags: memory, cobol, overwrite, cics, microfocus

I'm using CICS in Cobol program and I've noticed that sometimes data are written out of the CICS memory. It cause a data corruption and my application stop. I don't know where it append, so I'm creating a parser to analyse my Cobol code to look for possible corruption in COMMAREA used by CICS. Now I checked following statements :

```
EXEC CICS XCTL
EXEC CICS LINK
EXEC CICS RETURN TRANSID
```

For each, I check if sent length (declared in `LENGTH` parameter) is not greater than sent `COMMAREA`. Then I check if `DFHCOMMAREA`, in the receiving program is not greater than sent `COMMAREA` (according to this doc http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v3r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.cics.ts31.doc%2Fdfhp3%2Fdfhp37t.htm) :

***The receiving data area need not be of the same length as the original communication area; if access is required only to the first part of the data, the new data area can be shorter. However, it must not be longer than the length of the communication area being passed. If it is, your transaction may inadvertently attempt to read data outside the area that has been passed. It may also overwrite data outside the area, which could cause CICS to abend.***

Now, I'm wondering what other things should I parse in order to detect memory overwritting?

Comment: Writing a robust COBOL parser is a big job. If you are using IBM Enterprise COBOL, I suggest that you explore using compiler ADATA option to generate an AST and go from there. The type of static code analysis needed to detect bounds errors is technically impossible to get absolutely right. Static analysis is based on the syntatical structure of a program, not the semantics of the program so determining the actual run-time behaviour is pretty much impossible.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Microfocus NetExpress compiler. And, in fact, it's pretty hard to determine semantic in static analysis. Actually I'm trying to find out all "paths" that can be done in the code and determine if some of them can create errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a CICS program starts writing all over memory it will not only "stop working" but possibly
crash the CICS region as well!

If you are sure that the `LENGTH` is set properly on `LINK`s and `XCTL`s and that you are
receiving the `COMMAREA` into a linkage record of that size (`EIBCALEN`), then you should
be fine.

Rather than trying to parse your COBOL programs I suggest that you set compiler
bounds checking options on. The problem you are having is most likely related to
indexing or subscripting beyond the bounds of a working storage table. Attempting to detect
this class of programming error through static analysis is generally not very
effective.

Setting bounds
checking on should detect out of range memory references, issue a diagnostic message to
the log, and then and terminate your program
before it crashes the whole CICS region. The logged message should point you the the
source line where the out of bounds reference occured.

Check out the `SSRANGE` compile time option. Make sure it is set and that your CICS region
runs LE enabled programs with `CHECK(ON)`.

This should nail out of bounds memory
references pretty quickly.

Comment: Ok thanks for the hint I will try to see how it work. Actually the aim of my work is to parse Cobol programs(no run), not to use CICS log. So I will try to find out a way to add this check tool from CICS in my parser.

Answer (score 1):

NealB has a [good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9007660/624463).  I suggest you also look into the [STGPROT](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.6?topic=summary-stgprot) and [RENTPGM](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.6?topic=summary-rentpgm) CICS [system initialization parameters](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.6?topic=region-specifying-cics-system-initialization-parameters).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll look if I can use those parameters, I'm using Unikix environnement not IBM, I don't know if they exist too.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Micro Focus COBOL, you could set the memory_strategy tunable (or the CBL_MEM_STRATEGY API) to help you analysis where the error is occurring by allowing the runtime to protect memory in various different ways.

Memory can also be validate via the "CBL_MEM_VALIDATE" call.

Another thing can do is use the tracing support... lookup CTF (Consolidated Tracing Facility).   This will give you an idea where you code is at the time of the error.

Some References that will help you;

http://kb.microfocus.com/display/4/kb/article.aspx?aid=31645

http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.microfocus.eclipse.infocenter.studee60win.sp02ws01%2FHRRTRHRTCF0O.html

http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.microfocus.eclipse.infocenter.studee60ux.sp02ws01%2FGUID-762085AC-8396-4D71-9CC1-6231551D3AEE.html

Answer (score 1):

For the passing-of-data bounds checking, always use [transclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transclusion), which in COBOL is called a COPYCODE or COPYBOOK. Pass the root data element in the copycode, and compile the same version in the caller and called program. This COPYCODE is sortof the contract for the called program, so it is a good idea to have a naming convention tying them together. To make sure they are in-sync, whenever you change the COPYCODE, recompile all programs that reference it.

Also, the use of SSRANGE is great (but someone already mentioned that).